# Word similar to patented but not legally patented?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What is a word similar to "patented" but without the legal connotation? It is something that only you or your company offers. May be a methodology rather than a product.

Comment: Do you really want a term without legal connotations/implications, or just one where no official legal registration took place?

Answer (score 7):

> **Proprietary**
>   [pruh-prahy-i-ter-ee] 
>   /adjective
>
> 3. pertaining to property or ownership.
> 4. belonging or controlled as property.
> 5. (of a brand name, product, service, formula, etc.) protected by a patent, copyright, or trademark:
>      proprietary drugs; a proprietary name; a proprietary logo; a proprietary blend of ingredients.
> 6. privately owned and operated for profit.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/proprietary)

Comment: Thank you! Proprietary is the word I was trying to think of.

Comment: @S.Turnoy happy to help

Answer (score 5):

A trade secret:

> trade se·cret
>
> noun: trade secret; plural noun: trade secrets
>
> a secret device or technique used by a company in manufacturing its
>    products.

United States:

> The Uniform Trade Secrets Act ("UTSA") defines a trade secret as:
>
> information, including a formula, pattern, compilation, program, device,
>   method, technique, or process,
>      that derives independent economic value, actual or potential, from not 
>   being generally known to or readily ascertainable through
>   appropriate means by other persons who might obtain economic value
>   from its disclosure or use; and
>       is the subject of efforts that are reasonable under the circumstances to 
>    maintain its secrecy.
>
> The UTSA has been enacted, in one form or another, by 40 states and
>   the District of Columbia.  Prior the the development of the UTSA,
>   improper use or disclosure of a trade secret was traditionally a
>   common law tort. Sections 757 and 758 of the Restatement of Torts
>   (1939) set forth the basic principles of trade secret law that were
>   widely adopted by U.S. courts.  In particular, § 757, comment b,
>   listed six factors to be considered in determining whether information
>   constitutes a trade secret: . . .

For more information see:

https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/trade_secret

Example:  The formula for making Coca-Cola is a trade secret.

Although trade secrets (unlike patents) do not originate in law, they are protected (under various circumstances) by law.